# I'm using .done() incorrectly, doesn't return value as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, deferred

I am trying to use jQuery's AJAX deferreds to return a JSON string that can be parsed and used but I have coded myself into a corner and may have screwed up the logic. I expected the results of the AJAX call to be returned in the `.done()` callback *and they are*. I thought once done that I could return the result for use in the remainder of the function. I know that I'm missing something really obvious and simple, I just cannot put a finger on what it is.

Here is the initial coding of the function, stil very much in test mode. The JSON is correctly returned in the `.done()` function but I cannot assign it outside of the function for use.

```
checkUserRoles = function(){
    var userRole, foo, roles, i$, len$, i;
    userRole = roleChecker();
    foo = userRole.done(function(data){
        var bar;
        bar = foo.responseText; // correctly returns the JSON data
        console.log(bar);
        return bar; //  is undefined, this is the problem
    });
    if (userRole !== false) {
        userRole = jsonDecode(userRole);
    } else {
        userRole = "";
    }
    roles = userRole.split(',');
    $("if-user-role").hide();
    for (i$ = 0, len$ = roles.length; i$ < len$; ++i$) {
        i = roles[i$];
        $("if-user-role[data-role~=" + i + "]").show();
    }
    return true;
};
this.roleChecker = function(){
    var retVal, allCookies, i$, len$, thecookie, hashedCookie, theHash, userHash, post;
    retVal = "";
    allCookies = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (i$ = 0, len$ = allCookies.length; i$ < len$; ++i$) {
        thecookie = allCookies[i$];
        if (thecookie.indexOf('userHash') >= 0) {
            hashedCookie = thecookie;
            theHash = hashedCookie.split('=');
            userHash = theHash[1];
        }
    }
    post = $.ajax({
        url: '/services/check_hash.php',
        data: {
            hash: userHash
        },
        type: "POST"
    });
    return post;
};
```

The code that you see here is the output from the compiling of LiveScript which we use extensively. I don't think the LiveScript is having an effect on the final result, I just had to do a lot to get what I expected would be the proper JavaScript / jQuery output.

**NOTE**: because this is more or less the first pass at the code `foo` doesn't get passed along to the subsequent if statement as `userRole` was originally hard-coded for the initial testing prior to trying to make the function more dynamic.

How do I return `foo.responseText` or `bar` for use in the subsequent procedure? Do I need to put the procedure, beginning with the `if` conditional in the `.done()` function?

Comment: Upvote for admitting that you're using it incorrectly and not saying that it's not working the way it should

Comment: Not sure why my close vote got removed, but this is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `.then` and not `.done`.

What `.done` does is perform an action and return *the same promise*. On the other hand `then` returns a new promise which is resolved with the return value of the callback provided to it. (Assuming the `$.ajax` resolved correctly).

You of course then need to place everything you subsequently do in the chain:

```
userRole.then(function(data){
    var bar;
    bar = foo.responseText; // correctly returns the JSON data
    console.log(bar);
    return bar;
}).then(function(role){;
  if (role != false) {
    role = jsonDecode(userRole);
  } else {
    userRole = "";
  }
//...
  return true;
});
```

You should also `return` that promise to hook on it later.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using deferred objects synchronously, which (as you mentioned in your title) is not the intended purpose.  The code that you process the user data with after `.done()` will execute immediately after registering that handler, so your data won't be ready yet.

When you register a `.then()` on a deferred promise, you're telling your program to run a piece of code after the deferred object has either resolved or rejected.  The program **will not wait** until that deferred object has resolved or rejected, it will continue processing code (which is the beauty of the deferred object system!)

Example:

```
var checkUserRoles = function () {
    var userRole = roleChecker();

    // go off and find the user data
    // but *don't wait for it before continuing code execution*
    userRole.then(function(data){

      // at this point the AJAX request has finished, and we have the data
      console.log(data);

      // put code to process the user data here
    });

    // code here is executed immediately after registering the .then handler
    // so the user data has not loaded yet
};

var roleChecker = function () {
    var defer = $.Deferred();
    var post = defer.promise();

    // simulate an AJAX Request, returns after 2 seconds
    setTimeout(function () {
      defer.resolve('user data here!');   
    }, 2000);

    return post;
};

checkUserRoles();
```